# Linux blocking udp socket won't receive

Tags: linux, sockets, ubuntu-9.04

I am openning a udp blocking socket on an ubuntu machine, it goes successful (no errors returned).

When sending data to that machine and port from another machine the receive doesnt breaches and in a wireshark sniffer I see and Icmp error "port unreachable".

I though it might be an iptables problem and opened the port for accept.

Any other suggestions how to debug this?

Thanks.

Timmy

Comment: why are you seeing icmp error port unreachable? ICMP and UDP are completely different things.

Comment: Tom: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_Destination_Unreachable

Comment: Q. I see and Icmp error "port unreachable"
A. ICMP does not use ports.

Comment: debugging suggestions: try from the loopback on the local machine. If that works, perhaps you need to mess with your router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show a minimal test case.

Do you see your process in

```
sudo netstat -4lp
```

? What local address is its socket bound to (as reported by netstat)?

Comment: Tried this and in the list returned the problematic socket doesn't seem to appear. However I do see others socket I openned in the program.

Comment: Perhaps bind() failed. Do you check its return value? errno then should give you a hint on what's wrong.

(Wild guess) Did you try to bind to the low port without root privileges?

Please, show us the code.

Comment: Your answer helped spotting the bug. The socket was opened and then closed because of an uninitiated socket descriptor. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I usually use `netcat` to figure out if the problem comes from the network/firewall or from my own code

try running a test server with `netcat` :
eg.

```
nc -l -u -p 9999
```

will open and listen an udp socket, port 9999.

Now you can try to send a packet from the same or from another computer using

```
nc -u <ipaddress> 9999
```

Then type something and see if it reaches the first computer.

There are a lot of other cool stuffs in netcat, have a look on the manual.

Comment: Great idea, Thanks! did it and I see the incoming data, so it's probably something with the socket. Question is what? since no error is returned when openning and binding it...

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `bind()` to correctly bind the socket to the local port?

Did you remember to pass the local port number through `htons()` to convert it to network byte order?

What value did `bind()` return?

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple server and see if it works for you:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSZ 4096
#define PORTNUM 1099
char buffer[BUFSZ];

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    socklen_t clilen = sizeof( cliaddr );
    ssize_t nread;

    if (( fd = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 )) == -1 )
        err( 1, "socket" );

    bzero( &cliaddr, sizeof( cliaddr ));
    bzero( &servaddr, sizeof( servaddr ));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );
    servaddr.sin_port = htons( PORTNUM );

    if ( bind( fd, ( struct sockaddr* )&servaddr, sizeof( servaddr )) == -1 )
        err( 1, "bind" );

    printf( "bound to %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa( servaddr.sin_addr ),
        ntohs( servaddr.sin_port ));

    while (( nread = recvfrom( fd, buffer, BUFSZ, 0,
        ( struct sockaddr* )&cliaddr, &clilen )) != -1 )
    {
        printf( "received %lu bytes from %s:%d\n", nread,
            inet_ntoa( cliaddr.sin_addr ),
            ntohs( cliaddr.sin_port ));
    }

    return 1;
}
```

See if all the required steps are there in your code.